# Why do we need AML - ACPI Machine Language?

Tags: bios, firmware, uefi, acpi

As I understand, ACPI defines a generic hardware programming model where operating system relies on the OEM firmware provided AML (ACPI machine language) code to manipulate the hardware.

In order to execute the AML code, operating system has to incorporate an AML interpreter.

So, it looks to me that firmware developers use AML to provide a control interface between platform hardware and operating system.

But do we really need AML?

I think ***ultimately*** the hardware can ***only*** be configured through the ***native*** instruction of the platform. So the AML interpreter must translate the AML into native instructions otherwise it cannot be executed on the platform.

But what's the point of using an ***intermediate language*** like AML? I mean though the AML is said to be *platform-independent*, which means I can use AML to describe my platform in a *non-native* way.

But the AML is part of the platform firmware in practice. And the entire firmware has already been built into the target platform's native instructions. ***So what good can it be to make such a little part of the firmware as platform-independent?*** Why not just use native instructions? There ***must*** be some way to let OS use it as well. And this way operating system doesn't need the AML interpreter at all. A lot of complexity can be avoided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the big goals of ACPI over its predecessor APM was to give the OS more viability and control over power state transitions.

APM was a black box. The OS knew nothing about the power management implementation. It would just call a BIOS function and the BIOS handled all of the magic. Did it work?  Did the system sleep properly? Did the system freeze?  Was a user application able to handle the BIOS implementation?  The sad truth was that many systems had power management that was downright broken, and Microsoft wanted to provide a better power management experience for the growing laptop industry.

Now, the BIOS hands the ASL/AML code over to the OS and **the OS executes it not the BIOS**. If the BIOS code does something dumb (like messing with registers it shouldn't), Windows can detect that by parsing the code and block it. AML is 100% decompilable unlike C.

Remember that ACPI is not x86 specific. At the time it was developed, Itanium and Xscale were around. Intel and Microsoft needed a language that would work on all platforms, both 32 and 64 bit.

Lastly, ASL is more than just a list of executable functions. It is also number of static configuration tables. The ASL code has tables to define the non PnP hardware built onto your motherboard.  It has tables of supported power states.  A traditional programming language like C isn't really setup for that.

If ACPI was invented today, they would probably use something like XML to provide the info to the OS.

Answer (score 6):

Originally, hardware for "80x86 PC" was cloned from IBM's PC, and this created an effective de-facto standard for hardware to follow. However it didn't take long before manufacturers wanted to add features that didn't previously exist, where there was no (official or de-facto) standard to follow.

This led to a major problem for operating system software (how do you support "non-standard chaos"). Some standards were created for some things (APM, etc) but they didn't really cover everything needed and became out-of-date. ACPI was created to fix this.

Ideally, what was (and still is) needed is standards that allow operating system to detect and use supported features of the motherboard. For example, a "standardised case temperature and fan control" device (with support for detecting how many fans, temperature sensors, etc), or a "standardised CPU speed/power consumption", a "PCI slot IRQ routing for IO APICs" standard, a "hot-plug PCI controller device" standard, etc.

However, ACPI didn't provide useful standards that hardware manufacturers and operating systems can use. Instead, ACPI provided an over-engineered mess (AML) to allow an OS to cope with ACPI's failure to standardise the hardware.

Essentially; we "need" AML now because it's the only viable way for an OS to work-around the "non-standard chaos" problem that ACPI failed to fix.

The problem with providing native code instead of AML is that different operating systems use CPUs in different ways (e.g. native 64-bit 80x86 code in firmware would be useless for an older "32-bit only" OS). AML provides portability between different types of CPUs and between the same CPU/s in different modes.

Also; native code is considered a major security problem (rootkits, etc); and people tend to think an interpreted language mitigates that problem. Of course in practice AML needs far too much access to the underlying hardware and does it in a way that an OS can't check, and there's isn't even a way for an OS to determine if the AML has been maliciously modified before the OS booted. For these reasons AML is still a major security problem despite using interpreted language.